# Is it possible to hide/show line chart with a toggle button in VizFrame

Tags: charts, sapui5, line

Apologies in advance, I cannot share the code. I do have a screenshot.
[Screenshot][1]

I am using VizFrame vizType 'combination' which is a combination of columns and lines. I want to be able to hide/show just the line charts for the user to have an option. I have looked everywhere but cannot find a way. All I am able to do is hide data point labels which is not my requirement.

But please let me know if this is possible? If so, how can I can hide/show a line chart on click of a toggle button I have in my toolbar.

I'm using ui5 version 1.52

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that if you cannot find a way to do that it means that it's not possible with the standard version of the control.

You have two options:

1. Extend the current VizFrame control you're using in order to
   override/implement what you need
2. Use a third-party control to
   display charts. I would recommend you to check out my implementation
   of [openui5-chartjs](https://github.com/StErMi/openui5-chartjs)